# Plesk 11 faulty internal redirection

Tags: redirect, subdomain

I've just upgraded a website from Plesk-9 (Ubuntu 8) to Plesk-11 (CentOS 6.3).

The Plesk-11 server was created with a specific subdomain "sub.example.com", this also became the default webspace. Then the old site was migrated using the migration manager, with the same domain "sub.example.com".

When accessing sub.example.com from a browser or an external server, everything works fine; files are being served from "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/subdomains/sub/httpdocs".

But when the site itself links internally (from PHP running on the same server) to sub.example.com, file try to be hosted from "var/www/html" instead; the default page.
Same if I try to use wget from SSH on the Plesk-11 server.

How do I fix it so even internal calls to "sub.example.com" go to the directory I want?

Comment: How the internal like would normally look like at your site? Is it relative file path? absolute file path? full qualified URL?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution myself; removing the "sub.example.com" entry from /etc/hosts fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reconfigure the website using the following utility:

/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng --reconfigure-domain domain_name

And check after this, this will fix the issue.